# finding the largest digit in an integer using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have a practice who's task is to find the largest digit in an integer using recursion in java. For example, for the number 13441 the digit '4' will be returned.

I have been trying for a day now and nothing worked.

What I thought could work is the following code, which I can't quite get the "base case" for:

```
public static int maxDigit(int n) {
    int max;
    if (n/100==0) {
        if (n%10>(n/10)%10) {
            max=n%10;
        }
        else
            max=(n/10)%10;
    }
    else if (n%10>n%100)
        max=n%10;
    else
        max=n%100;
    return maxDigit(n/10);
}
```

As you can see it's completely wrong.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: @Baadshah: I don't see why that's necessary for this question. The code is perfectly readable without.

Comment: One thing to change is what you return. You should return the greater of `max` & `maxDigit(n/10)`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or something? I can't think of a worse place to use recursion.

Comment: Your code as it stands now will go into infinite loop. There is no coming out from recursion.

Comment: @ColinD -  thank you but I can't figure out how to "save" the max value.

Comment: pass in the max as a parameter and only overwrite it if the new max found is greater than the old max from the previous recursion.

Comment: @dkaustubh - I know, that's why I'm here :)

Comment: @MikeMcMahon there's no need to pass the current "max" as a parameter.

Comment: Also, you need a return that just returns the max at some point...e.g. when the division of n = 0 through and you've obtained the largest value from max.

Comment: @EdwardFalk - homework. I hope no firm ever uses recursion in such a manner.

Comment: @Assaf in some languages (i.e. functional languages) recursion would be the natural way to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest base case, is that if n is 0, return 0.

```
public static int maxDigit(int n){
    if(n==0)                               // Base case: if n==0, return 0
        return 0;
    return Math.max(n%10, maxDigit(n/10)); // Return max of current digit and 
                                           // maxDigit of the rest 
}
```

or, slightly more concise;

```
public static int maxDigit(int n){
    return n==0 ? 0 : Math.max(n%10, maxDigit(n/10));
}
```

Comment: this is technically the same algorithm as mine, albeit written slightly differently.

Comment: awww. very lovely !

Answer (score 7):

This works by recursively comparing the right most digit with the highest digit of the remaining digits (those being obtained by dividing the original number by 10):

```
int maxDigit(int n) {
    n = Math.abs(n);   // make sure n is positive
    if (n > 0) {
        int digit = n % 10;
        int max = maxDigit(n / 10);
        return Math.max(digit, max);
    } else {
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't think `int` evaluates to `true` or `false` in java

Comment: if (n) is not valid java syntax

Comment: oops - good point!  I tested the algorithm using JS, but not the syntax in a real Java compiler.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

I won't dig into your code, which I think is more complicated than it has to be.  But it seems to me that the cases are actually fairly simple (unless I'm missing something):

base case: parameter only has one digit, return that one digit as parameter

general case: return whichever is higher of (the first digit in the parameter) and (the maxDigit of the remaining digits in the parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You may also write:

```
public static int maxDigit(int n, int max){
    if(n!=0)    {
        if(n%10 > max) {
            max = n%10;
        }
        return maxDigit(n/10, max);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

```
    public static int maxDigit(int n, int max){
        if (n!=0){
            if ( n%10 > max){
                max = n%10;
                return maxDigit(n/10,max);
            }else{
                return maxDigit(n/10,max);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```